# How can I reconstruct linear indices for a filtered 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have the following numpy array

```py
>>> arr = np.array([[0,1,0,1],
                    [0,0,0,1],
                    [1,0,1,0]])
```

where values of `0` indicate "valid" values and values of `1` indicate "invalid" values. Next, suppose that I filter out the invalid `1` values as follows:

```py
>>> mask = arr == 1
>>> arr_filt = arr[~mask]
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

If I want to go from a linear index of a valid value (`0`) in the original `arr` to the linear index of the same value in the new filtered `arr_filt`, I can proceed as follows:

```py
# record the cumulative total number of invalid values
num_invalid_prev = np.cumsum(mask.flatten())

# example of going from the linear index of a valid value in the
# original array to the linear index of the same value in the
# filtered array
ij_idx = (0,2)
linear_idx_orig = np.ravel_multi_index(ij_idx,arr.shape)
linear_idx_filt = linear_idx_orig - num_invalid_prev[linear_idx_orig]
```

However, I'm interested in going the other way. That is, given the linear index of a valid value in the filtered `arr_filt` and the same `num_invalid_prev` array, can I get back the linear index of the same valid value in the unfiltered `arr`?

Comment: Not sure if it is useful, but look into `numpy.argwhere`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to get indices:

```py
ix = np.c_[np.nonzero(~mask)]
>>> ix
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 3]])
```

Then, you can for example look up the index of the second valid value:

```py
>>> tuple(ix[1])
(0, 2)

>>> arr[tuple(ix[1])]
0
```